# Modify a List of Lists in Ocaml

Tags: list, ocaml

I have a data such as :

```
3   11 12
15  13 14 15
```

I read it from file by:

```
let print data =
    List.iter (fun l -> printf "%s@." (String.concat " " l)) data

let read filename =
let ch = open_in filename in
let data = Lexer.lex [] (Lexing.from_channel ch) in
close_in ch;
print data
```

Out put is

```
3   11 12 
15  13 14 15
```

-> it is a list in a lists

And my problem is when I want to modify a list in a lists, it didn't work. For example:

```
let remove = function
    h :: t -> t
;;
let print data =
        List.iter (fun l -> remove l; printf "%s@." (String.concat " " l)) data
```

Please help me to fix it. 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the remove call :

```
let print data =
    List.iter (fun l ->  printf "%s@." (String.concat " " (remove l))) data
```

Comment: remove l does not modify l, it returns a list. Other point : The function remove is List.tl from the standard lib - and your remove function does not compile on my end (not all match).